# How can I add gradient to left and to right?

Tags: html, css, styles, styled-components

Goal is adding liner-gradient to left and to right.

I can add to  right but not  both at the same time

```
mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
to right,
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%
);

-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(
to right,
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%
);
```

The result should be like this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do an overlay with this:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
```

Comment: This only left side

Comment: https://codepen.io/dfoxlee/pen/zYLJbyE Seems like both sides to me.

Comment: I have cards there and cards above this bacground

Comment: https://codepen.io/radomir-radionov/pen/OJwoGLJ?editors=1111

Comment: https://codepen.io/dfoxlee/pen/zYLJbyE Don't put the cards in the overlay. The overlay goes on top.